# How To Delete All Files With A Certain Word in Them In C#

Tags: c#, windows, file, io, delete-file

So, I have a folder full of files. I want to delete all the files that contain a certain combination of character/letters/numbers/symbols *In the name of the file*.

I was wondering how I would go about doing this in C#?

All I know is that I would have to use `System.IO;`

Ok! Mods feel free to lock this post! Thanks to the comments below I got it working with the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;


namespace File_Deleter
{
    class Program
    {

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String path = "F:\\Downloads\\random";

        String[] fileNames = new String[20];
        fileNames = Directory.GetFiles(path);

        for (int i = 0; i <= 87; i++)
        {

            if (fileNames[i].Contains("(1)"))
            {
                 Console.WriteLine(fileNames[i]);
                 File.Delete( fileNames[i]);

            }

        }


        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

}

Comment: You want to check the file name or file content?

Comment: Get list of files, open files from this list one by one and seek for combinations of characters you need. If you'му  found one - then just delete a file.

Comment: Look at [Directory.GetFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getfiles(v=vs.110).aspx) and [File.Delete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete(v=vs.110).aspx). That's all you should need to get started.

Comment: Read [ask], share your research. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create list of patterns
2. ForEach pattern in patterns
3. Get list of files matches pattern
4. FroEach file in files
5. Delete file
6. End ForEach
7. End ForEach

OR

1. Get all files in directory
2. Search list of files for patterns and store matched file names
3. Delete all stored files

**HINT**

You can use [Directory.GetFiles — (String, String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx)

**About your code**

Unnecessary initialization

```
String[] fileNames = new String[20];
```

in this case better use `foreach` insteed `for`

```
froeach(var file in fileNames)
...
if (file .Contains("(1)"))
```

if you don't want use `foreach` never use `for` int this manner

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 87; i++)
```

Constant 87 in `i <= 87` is very very bad practise, use `fileNames.Length`

Comment: Thank you for not dumping code and [setting OP on fire](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/14651/meaning-of-give-a-man-a-fire-and-hes-warm-for-the-day-but-set-fire-to-him-and).

Comment: Thank you, I actually appreciate this style of response more, as it will help me learn, but I actually meant in the name of the file.

Comment: Thank you very much for your review of my code, I have learnt a lot tonight :)